# GPUImage Swift HelloWorld Example

Tags: swift, gpuimage

I'm trying to set up a hello-world-type GPUImage example in Swift.  The code builds without errors, but I get a plain white screen without an image.  Changing the background color of the `GPUImageView` to red in the storyboard changes the color on the device, but using the `setBackgroundColorRed(...)` method of the class has no effect.

Here are the steps I took to set this up:

1. Installed `GPUImage` with CocoaPods
2. Closed the project and reopened with the `.xcworkspace`
3. Put `#include "GPUImage.h"` in a bridging file header
4. Dragged a generic `UIView` into the storyboard, added `autolayout` constraints, changed its class to `GPUImageView`, and created an outlet in my `ViewController` class
5. Created a `GPUImagePicture` from a photo in my application bundle
6. Added the view as a target of the picture and processed the image

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let image = GPUImagePicture(image: UIImage(named: "cameraman.png"))
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: GPUImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.image.addTarget(self.imageView)
        self.image.processImage()
    }

}
```

If I print out the `imageView` or the `image` I get non-null-looking pointers, and the `imageView` has a non-zero-looking frame.  Oddly, I've used GPUImage in other projects without any issue, and can't think what I have done differently this time--I'm sure it's something very small that I'm missing, but I can't seem to put my finger on it.  I uploaded the project here:

https://bitbucket.org/DVigneault/stack/downloads

**Edit:**

I'm using XCode 6.3 and iOS 8.3

**Edit 2:**

Same result after updating to XCode 6.3.1

**Edit 3:**

If I add `self.image.processImage()` in `viewDidAppear`, I get the desired result (that is, an image appears).  It occurs to me that any time I've used `GPUImage` in the past, I've called `processImage()` at least once after the view appeared.  Is it *always* necessary to call `processImage()` after the view appears?

Comment: Your example code works for me, try a clean build and set the outlet to the imageView again.

Comment: Thanks @yene for checking out the project.  I just tried rebuilding/resetting the outlet, but no change.  Out of curiosity, what XCode and iOs versions did you try on?

Comment: I am using Xcode 6.3.1 with iOS 8.3

Comment: @PyNewb did you get it to work? I'm getting the same issue with same Xcode/iOS versions. I'm using Obj. C.

Comment: I tried your example and it works in Xcode 7.2